# Compiler error because constructor must explicitly initialize the member

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor, compiler-errors

I have class `CFirst` and `CSecond`.
I can't do anything with the second class, but I can do something with the first one.
I am trying to create an object from the second one in the first one, but the compiler is still not satisfied.

The best so far is this:

```
class CFirst{
    public:
    CSecond m_sec;
    CFirst ( const CSecond & sec ) {
          CSecond m_sec(sec.a(),sec.b());
     };

class CSecond{
    public:
    CSecond ( int a, int b) : m_A ( a ), m_B ( b ){ }
    int a  ( void ) const { return m_A;  }
    int b ( void ) const { return m_B; }
    private:
    int m_A;
    int m_B;
};
```

but complier says:

> constructor for 'CFirst' must explicitly initialize the member 'm_sec'
>   which does not have a default constructor.

Do you have some advice?

EDIT:

I did also try (no success)

```
 m_sec(sec.a(),sec.b());
```

instead of

```
 CSecond m_sec(sec.a(),sec.b());
```

The explanation is in comments below answer.

Comment: The correct syntax for initializing members is the one you used in `CSecond` for `m_A` and `m_B`.

Comment: Also, you need to declare `CSecond` before you can refer to it in `CFirst::CFirst(const CSecond&)`, so your class definitions are out of order here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside the constructor of `CFirst`, `CSecond m_sec(sec.a(),sec.b());` doesn't initialize the member `m_sec`, but defines a local object with name `m_sec`, which has nothing to do with the member `m_sec`. (And it hides the member `m_sec`.)

You should use [member intializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) instead, e.g.

```
CFirst ( const CSecond & sec ) : m_sec(sec.a(), sec.b()) {} // initialize data member m_sec via CSecond::CSecond(int, int)
```

or

```
CFirst ( const CSecond & sec ) : m_sec(sec) {} // initialize data member m_sec via CSecond's copy constructor
```

**Additional explanations**

[Non-static data members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) can only be initialized by member intializer list or default intializer list (since C++11). You just can't do it inside the constructor's body. So `CSecond m_sec(sec.a(),sec.b());` will define a new local variable, and `m_sec = sec;` is an assignment; before the assignment `m_sec` will be tempted to be default intialized. But `CSecond` doesn't have default constructor, which cause the compile error.

Comment: Cool thanks. Works as expected. Could you please describe more, why the solution I used, is not good? I still don't understand it completely...

Comment: @TGar I explained it in the 1st paragraph, which part you don't understand?

Comment: Instead of initializing `this->m_sec`, you create a separate local variable with the same name that *hides* the class member.

Comment: The solution posted here is better, but `m_sec = sec;` inside the constructor would also have worked.

Comment: @Davislor this: "m_sec(sec.a(),sec.b());" instead of "CSecond m_sec(sec.a(),sec.b());" doesn't work too, why?

Comment: Oh sorry, that is just a typo because of copypaste, I meant the one you wrote. But I think it didn't work for me.

Comment: @TGar I added some additional explanations.

Comment: Ah, I was mistaken when I said you could assign inside `CFirst::CFirst()`; there would still need to be a default constructor `CSecond::CSecond()`.  If you really want one, you could add `CSecond() : m_A(0), m_B(0) {}`—but beware; that would have hidden the bug here and you’d be wondering why all `CFirst` objects get initialized to zeros!

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. Thanks to both of you.
(@Davislor as he is not pinged automatically)